# How to fix "too many initializers for `some struct with template`"

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a structure called WtHasher

```
template <typename V>
struct WtHasher {
    Ul (*hasher(V&));
    bool (*comparator(V&, V&));
};
```

When I try to make an object of this structure using curly-brace-ish style, I get an error

```
... some code ...

WtHasher<int> hasher = {
        [] (int &k) {return (Ul)k;},
        [] (int &a, int &b) {return a == b;}
};

... some code ...
```

Error:

```
error: too many initializers for ‘WtHasher<int>’
};
^
```

Why is that? There are 2 fields in the structure and 2 fields in braces, so it should fit.

Comment: Are your warnings on? On my GCC with `-Wall -Wextra` I got `main.cpp:7:8: warning: unnecessary parentheses in declaration of 'hasher' [-Wparentheses]`.

Comment: I forgot to put -Wall flags -- I'm new to cpp. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `Ul (*hasher)(V&);` and `bool (*comparator)(V&, V&);` if you want to declare pointers to functions. Otherwise it's just a member function declaration (see [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)).

Comment: It's not really the most vexing parse though ;)

Comment: Indeed, but the idea is kind of similar, imho.